# How can I make one on one combat more epic in Cyberpunk 2020?

Tags: house-rules, martial, cyberpunk-2020

I would like more detail in fights between martial artists, to simulate a traditional Kung fu showdown.

The regular system works well for combat with a group, but is too generic for the epic one-on-one battle between two skilled martial artists...roll one d10 and figure out damage for a called shot to the head with a hammer fist, and the guy is dead in one melee moment.

I'd rather have a system that has planned moves...similar to the old game "Swashbuckler", but with martial arts moves. Integrating such a system with CP2020 might be difficult though, so any advice from someone who has done a similar conversion would be helpful.

Comment: Soliciting recommendations doesn't really work in this Q&A system—you just end up with a pile of ideas of dubious quality. Which would be fine, except the way this site is set up doesn't handle piles of ideas of dubious quality gracefully, so we don't try to force it to. For this question, you might want a more traditional discussion forum (like [one of the ones on this list](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449)). Alternatively, do you want to open this up to just asking “How can I have a more interesting martial arts duel in CP2020?” without *requiring* a system suggestion as the answer?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, so tried to coerce it into 'good subjective' territory @SevenSidedDie.